Path rotate transformation problem in MAUI
When I change the angle to 90 I expect this:

but I get this instead:

What am I doing wrong?
XAML:

<Grid WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start">
<Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />

<Path Fill="Blue" Aspect="Uniform" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
        Data="M 0,0 .5,.5 0,1 0,0">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>

<Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="{Binding Width}" Y2="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Black" />
<Line X1="{Binding Width}" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Black" />


Your problem is complex.
One part of it is that your Path is covering only half of the grid. If you want it to render, you need to make sure that it fills all the space.
For now you can place:
<Path WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"...

Second part of the problem is how the aspect is placing the triangle on the canvas.
If you just make the first change, you will see a centered triangle, that rotates around itself.
For now you can replace Aspect and Data with this:
... Data="M 0,0 50,50 0,100 0,0" Aspect="None" ...

Another way to rotate like that is by applying chains of transformations.
Without changing the data and the aspect, you can replace your RotateTransform, with TransformGroup.
<TransformGroup>
   <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
   <TranslateTransform X="-25"/>
</TransformGroup>


You should put the Path in a Grid and apply rotation to the Grid, i.e.
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" />
    <Grid Rotation="90">
        <Path
            Aspect="Uniform"
            Data="M 0,0 .5,.5 0,1 0,0"
            Fill="Blue"
            HorizontalOptions="Start" />
    </Grid>
    <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="{Binding Width}" Y2="{Binding Height}" />
    <Line Stroke="Black" X1="{Binding Width}" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="{Binding Height}" />
</Grid>

This works because the inner Grid will take on the same dimensions as the outer Grid and apply the rotation to the center of the grid.
